# Adding an onClick action in the controller of a Zend button

Tags: zend-framework, button, view, controller, action

I'm new to Zend and I want to make a simple page with a button that does something.
The thing that I don't get (despite reading a lot of online material) is how to create a corresponding action in the controller.

I have the following view script index.phtml:

```
<?php

echo $this->button1
```

another script called add.phtml :

```
<?php echo $this->json($this->data);
```

and a controller:

```
class blabla extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {

        $addButton = new Zend_Form_Element_Button("button",array('class' => 'btn_op', 'action'=>'add' , 'id' => 'addbtn')); //button
        $addButton->setLabel("Add >>");
        //$addButton->setAttrib('onclick', 'alert("Hello!")'); //not what I want
        $this->view->button1 = $addButton->render(null);


    }

    public function addAction() {

        echo 'I want my code to go here on click';

    }

}
```

Thanks 
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
class blabla extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {

        $addButton = new Zend_Form_Element_Button("button",array('class' => 'btn_op', 'action'=>'add' , 'id' => 'addbtn')); //button
        $addButton->setLabel("Add >>");

        $url = $this->view->url( array('controller' => 'blabla', 'action' => 'add'), 'default', false);
        $addButton->setAttrib('onclick', 'window.location.replace("'.$url.'");');

        $this->view->button1 = $addButton->render(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your button from one action to go to the another action , You Can always use redirect helpers..

i assumed you are using Zf 1 and not zf 2 from your code..

you can directly redirect with following code,

```
 $this->_helper->redirector('your_action', 'Your_controller');
```

in your case

```
class blabla extends Zend_Controller_Action {
public function indexAction() {

    $addButton = new Zend_Form_Element_Button("submit",array('class' => 'btn_op', 'action'=>'add' , 'id' => 'addbtn')); //button
    $addButton->setLabel("Add >>");
    //$addButton->setAttrib('onclick', 'alert("Hello!")'); //not what I want
    $this->view->button1 = $addButton->render(null);
    $this->_helper->redirector('add', 'Your_controller');


}

public function addAction() {

    echo 'The Button was Pressed';

}
```

}

I am sure that will work , you can also check if the button is pressed or not, if you want , but this will basically submit the button and then redirect to your add action,..

Comment: Yea.. well it automatically redirects to the action page.. :\

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually just want to redirect or are you intending the form to submit data? Given the context of your question and that the button is labeled 'Add >>', I would have expected that you want to submit.

In this case, you should make the 'Add' button an instance of Zend_Form_Element_Submit and wrap it in a form that has the 'action' attribute of the form pointing to the addAction() method. For example:

```
class blabla extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {

        $addButton = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('add');
        $addButton->setLabel('Add >>');
        $addButton->setAttrib('id', 'addbtn')

        $this->view->button1 = $addButton->render();

    }

    public function addAction() {

        echo 'I want my code to go here on click';

    }

}
```

The corresponding view script:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->url( array('controller' => 'blabla', 'action' => 'add'), 'default', false) ?>" method="post">
  <?php echo $this->button1 ?>
</form>
```